# await http request response in constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a class, how I can create await for key value, that should be requested from http request in another method?

I don't know how to correct use await in this situation.

Here code, it returns only undefined:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(key = null) {
        if (!!key)
            this.key = key;
        else
            (async () => { this.key = await this.getKey(); })(); 
    }
    getKey(input) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let options,
                request,
                data = '';

            try {
                options = {
                    host: '...',
                    port: '80',
                    path: '/',
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                };
                request = http.request(options, (response) => {
                    response.setEncoding('utf8');
                    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                        data += chunk.toString();
                    });
                    response.on('end', () => {
                        resolve(new RegExp('<div id="...".*>(.*)<\/div>', 'g').exec(data)[1]);
                    });
                });
                request.end();
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a constructor to have asynchronous properties. I'd recommend just having the user call some method to set `this.key` asynchronously after object construction because constructors need to return immediately with a new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a better usage would be to use `await` for the var you'll put in parameter :

```
let key = await getKey();
let myClass = new MyClass(key);
```

Comment: but getKey is a method of myClass... so that first line can't work?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm as confused about `async await` as you are, but it doesn't really seem necessary in this scenario.

```
class MyClass {

    initKey() {
        this.getKey().then(d => { this.key = d })
    }

    getKey(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve("the promised value")
        })
    }
}

let t = new MyClass()
t.initKey()
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

Comment: Hmm, apparently, `async await` is not really necessary in this particular scenario.... If you return a promise you can call `then()` on it directly.

Comment: They don't wait for then.

Comment: `await` also doesn't wait... that's the whole idea behind async functions. If you WANT the code to wait for the key id you have to put your code inside the `then()`. It doesn't matter if you use `async await` or not!